# Dynamic loadChildren

Tags: angularjs, typescript, lazy-loading

I'm trying to dynamically import routes from a config file using that code:

```
export function buildRoutes(options: any, router: Router, roles: string[]): Routes {
    const lazyRoutes: Routes = Object.keys(options)
        .map((key) => {
            const entry: RouteConf = options[key];
            const auth = entry.authRoute as string[];
            let output: Route =   {
                path: entry.routePath,
                redirectTo: 'fallback',
            };
            if (auth.some(item => roles.includes(item))){
                console.log(entry.exposedModule,entry.ngModuleName);
                output = {
                    path: entry.routePath,
                    loadChildren: () => import(entry.exposedModule).then((m) => m[entry.ngModuleName])
                }
             }
            return output;
        });

    return [...lazyRoutes,...APP_ROUTES ];
}
```

but i get:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module '../richieste/richieste.module'
Error: Cannot find module '../richieste/richieste.module'
```

if I manually set the same data in the loadChildren, ie:

```
....
loadChildren: () => import( '../richieste/richieste.module').then((m) => m["RichiesteModule"])
....
```

everything works fine.

Is there a way to import modules dynamically in LazyLoading?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, when using dynamic imports for Lazy Loading in your code, the module paths are resolved relative to the location of the file containing the import statement. In your case, the `entry.exposedModule` value contains a relative path (`'../richieste/richieste.module'`), which causes the error because the module cannot be found.

To solve this issue, you can use the `import.meta.url` property, which provides the URL of the current module. By combining `import.meta.url` with the `new URL()` function, you can construct an absolute path to the module.

This is how you can address the `loadChildren` line:

```js
loadChildren: () => import(new URL(entry.exposedModule, import.meta.url).toString()).then((m) => m[entry.ngModuleName])
```

By using `new URL(entry.exposedModule, import.meta.url)`, you create an absolute URL to the module based on the current module's URL and the relative path specified in `entry.exposedModule`.

This adjustment ensures that the module path is resolved correctly, allowing you to import the modules dynamically in the Lazy Loading configuration.
Hope this works for you ;)

Comment: Locally I get `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'file:///C:/dir/subdir/src/app/richieste/richieste.module'`. It's the correct source path but I get the promise error. If deployed I get the same error, that's worse, because it is reported the same (local) path. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you import a module literally `import( '../richieste/richieste.module')`, it will automatically compiled by your scaffold (webpack or others).

but if you import a module dynamically `import(entry.exposedModule)`, it won't be compiled, you must compile it in an independent way, and provide a url to load it.

you can simply make a map that defining all modules you need, or use `module federation`, it's a good way to do this.

Comment: I'm switching back from a federated module architecture to a single app. Thanks